# ArcGIS labels with expression not appearing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, maplex

I have a layer which should be labelled based on two different fields. I've chang the Expression in Layer Properties from **[FIELD1]** to **[FIELD1] + '\n' + [FIELD2]**. However, only Field1 is showing in my map, never Field2. I have fixed the scale range and I am using the Maplex Label Engine. Why aren't both fields showing in my label?

Comment: `'\n'`  indicates Python parser, have you changed to that?

Comment: Can you make sure you actually have some values in Field2 for those features you are looking at? Another thing to try is to test labelling first without Maplex with standard labeling engine.

Comment: Although I had changed the Expression in Layer Properties (after a quick right click to the layer in the Data Frame), I found that I had to also change the Expression in the Label Manager. After doing so, both fields become visible.

Comment: just add your own answer and explain what to look for. It will help someone in the future. Be clear and show your work if possible (screen shots).

Comment: If you are using the VB parser then your expression should be: `[Field1] &vbNewLine & [Field2]`